# Stripe unable to retrieve subscription using API (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I am unable to retrieve my subscription object from stripe using react I have the following async function, however it is returning a null value when I change state.

The problem I feel is currently around the stripe.subscriptions.retrieve promise is correctly being implemented.

```
function ActiveSubscription(): JSX.Element | null {
  const [subscription, loading, error] = useFetch<AppSubscription>(
    'app_subscription',
    '?isActive==True'
  );

  const [subscriptionData, setSubscriptionData] = useState<any | null>(null);

  const subLoading = useEffectLoading(async () => {
    const stripe = require('stripe')(
      'SECRET_KEY'
    );
    const data = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve('SUBSCRIPTION_ID');
    setSubscriptionData(data);
    console.log(subscriptionData);
  }, [subscription]);

  console.log(subscriptionData);
  if (loading || !subLoading) return <Loading />;
  if (subscription == null) return null;
  if (error) {
    return <h1>Unable to fetch subscription.</h1>;
  }
```

The current console log outputs null.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Reading between the lines, it looks like snippets such as `require('stripe')` are intended to used in server-side implementations, i.e. on the backend.

NB: whatever happens, for your sake, please be mindful not to publish anything which is otherwise referred to as 'SECRET_KEY' in frontend code

Comment: For additional context, typically, services such as Stripe require that frontend implementations communicate with private backend implementations, which, in turn, handle some private communications with Stripe (frontend → backend → Stripe → backend → frontend). This architecture helps avoid leaking sensitive info to users, e.g. private keys with escalated privileges. It seems the Stripe-related code in this question is intended to be implemented on some backend. The proper FE implementation would be something that sends requests to an endpoint belonging to said backend

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Implemented the solution in the Backend. Completely agree with not exposing the SECRET_KEY in frontend code.
Thanks for your help!